# Prime Number Calculation using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script, math

Last line is not executing when the number is prime. Please help

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter Number : \c"
read n
while [ $n -gt 2 ]
do
for((i=2; i<=$n/2; i++))
do
  ans=$(( n%i ))
  if [ $ans -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$n is not a prime number."
    exit 0
  fi
done
done
echo "$n is a prime number."
```

---

The new code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter Number : \c"
read n
for((i=2; i<=$n/2; i++))
do
  ans=$(( n%i ))
  if [ $ans -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$n is not a prime number."
    exit 0
  fi
done
echo "$n is a prime number."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer while loop is infinite:

```
while [ $n -gt 2 ]
```

A working version:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter Number : \c"
read n
for((i=2; i<=$n/2; i++))
do
  ans=$(( n%i ))
  if [ $ans -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$n is not a prime number."
    exit 0
  fi
done
echo "$n is a prime number."
```

Comment: But last line is not executing I tried with 13.

Comment: @AnkitKumar Works for me.

Comment: The cursor keeps on blinking and does not show the number is prime . I'm using ubuntu 18

Comment: @AnkitKumar show the new code in [https://pastebin.com/](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @guillermochamorro no, please don't. The new code should be added to the question.

Comment: @terdon Ok, I thougth if it's the same code won't add nothing meaningful to the question, that's what my suggestion. :)

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes, fair enough. It's just that we want all relevant information _here_ not on external sites. Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: @guillermochamorro here is the link https://pastebin.com/NVJHyDVm

Comment: @AnkitKumar Please do not use the PasteBin or similar services here. We need to have relevant info directly in your question (if you feel it is relevant).

Comment: Your pastebin is just a copy paste of Jack's answer. @AnkitKumar

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I won't . I'd no idea about this. I won't do it again :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Enter number: " n

d=2
r=1 
while [[ $d -lt $n && $r -ne 0 ]]
do
        r=`expr $n % $d`

        d=`expr $d + 1`
done

if [[ $r -eq 0 ]]
  then
  echo "$n is not a prime number"
else
      echo "$n is a prime number"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

read j
 i=2
while (($i<$j))
do
   f=((j%i))
if [ $f -eq 0] && [ $j -ne $i ]
then
   # echo "is a not prime number"
  i=$i+$j
elif [ $f -ne 0 ]
then
   ((i++))
else [ $j -ne $i ]
then
echo "is a prime number"
fi
done
```